# Parsing strings with stop tokens

Tags: python, pyparsing

Assuming a parser that accepts the letters `a`, `b` and `c` and any combination of the three. I want to call a function with the substrings where the following conditions are met:

1. The substring starts with an `a`
2. The substring terminates before it encounters `abc`
3. The substring doesn't start with `abc`

So for example we have the following string:

`bb cc ab bc cb bc abc bca bbb acc cbc ccc abc`

I want to call the function with the strings `ab bc cb` and `acc cbc ccc`

I tried to implement this as follows:

```
import pyparsing as pp

x = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("abc") + ~pp.Literal("abc"))
x.addCondition(lambda tokens: tokens[0] != "abc")
x.addCondition(lambda tokens: tokens[0][0] == "a")
x.addParseAction(lambda tokens: print("x)", tokens))  # Print action for debugging

y = pp.Word("abc")
y.addParseAction(lambda tokens: print("y)", tokens))

text = pp.OneOrMore(x ^ y)
text.parseString("bb cc ab bc cb bc abc bca bbb acc cbc ccc abc")
```

But for some reason this *stops* 1 word too soon, here's the output:

```
y) ['bb']
y) ['cc']
x) ['ab', 'bc', 'bc']
y) ['cb']
y) ['abc']
y) ['bca']
y) ['bbb']
x) ['acc', 'cbc']
y) ['ccc']
y) ['abc']
```

Also, what if the `abc` stop token is a list of different strings that all would serve as a stop marker, how can I parse that?

So something like:

```
stopStrings = ["abc", "bca"]
x = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("abc") + ~pp.OneOf(stopStrings))
...
```

Hopefuly this makes it clear and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it. [This SO question/answer was very helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38642786/7274764) Bill Bell's answer helped me to get more than 1 termination string.

```
stop_strings = ["abc", "acb"]
stop_tokens = pp.Or([pp.Literal(sub) for sub in stop_strings])

x = pp.OneOrMore(~stop_tokens + pp.Word("abc")) + pp.Optional(stop_tokens.suppress())
x.addCondition(lambda tokens: tokens[0][0] == "a")
x.addParseAction(lambda tokens: print("x)", tokens))  # Print action for debugging

y = pp.Word("abc")
y.addParseAction(lambda tokens: print("y)", tokens))

text = pp.OneOrMore(x ^ y)
text.parseString("bb cc acb ab cb abc bca bbb acc cbc ccc")
```

output:

```
y) ['bb']
y) ['cc']
y) ['acb']
x) ['ab', 'cb']
y) ['bca']
y) ['bbb']
x) ['acc', 'cbc', 'ccc']
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be close to what you want. I don't understand your third condition.

- The definition of a `token` insists that it **not** be one of the `stop_tokens` and that it be a `Word` consisting of arbitrary letters from the set {a,b,c}.
- When a `token` is identified `setParseAction` sends a request that it be displayed if its first character is 'a'.
- The whole `parser` is just any number of `token`s followed by any number of `stop_token`s. Each `stop_token` is suppressed in this context. At the same time, if a `stop_token` is identified a message is emitted indicating that one has been seen.

Code:

```
import pyparsing as pp

def report_a(s):
    try:
        if s[0][0]=='a':
            print (s[0], "begins with 'a'")
    except:
        pass

def report(s):
    print ('stop token encountered')

stop_tokens = pp.Or([pp.Literal('abc'), pp.Literal('bca')])
token = pp.NotAny(stop_tokens) + pp.Word('abc').setParseAction(lambda s: report_a(s))
parser = pp.ZeroOrMore(token) + pp.ZeroOrMore(stop_tokens).setParseAction(lambda s: report(s)).suppress()

text = 'bb cc ab bc cb bc abc bca bbb acc cbc ccc abc'

print (parser.parseString(text))
```

Result:

```
ab begins with 'a'
stop token encountered
['bb', 'cc', 'ab', 'bc', 'cb', 'bc']
```

Comment: Not quite, but you pushed me in the right direction, see my update on the question.

Comment: Moved the update to a separate answer so that I can mark the question as answered.